# Cannot access query result value from select_related() in html file

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to join 3 tables and want attributes from all 3 tables. I have used select_related('goal_id','mealtype_id') so it gives me all attributes from 3 tables. I converted the query into raw and print it. Then in html template I cannot get "g_name" and "mt_name" value IDK why. Please take a look on my code and snapshot

**This is view method:**

```
def mealslist(request):
    meals = Meals.objects.select_related('mealtype_id','goal_id')

    print(meals.query)
    return  render(request,'meals_list.html',{'table':meals})
```

**This is raw query:**

```
SELECT `meals`.`id`, `meals`.`goal_id_id`, `meals`.`mealtype_id_id`, `meals`.`name`, `meals`.`quantity`, `meals`.`calories`, `meals`.`day_time`, `goal`.`id`, `goal`.`g_name`, `meal_type`
.`id`, `meal_type`.`mt_name` FROM `meals` LEFT OUTER JOIN `goal` ON (`meals`.`goal_id_id` = `goal`.`id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `meal_type` ON (`meals`.`mealtype_id_id` = `meal_type`.`id`)
```

**This is html table code:**

```
<tbody>
                  {% for f in table %}
                    <tr>
                         <td>{{f.id}}</td>

                         <td>{{f.g_name}}</td>

                        <td><a href="/mealtype/delete/{{f.id}}">Delete</a><br>
                          <a href="/mealtype/update/{{f.id}}">Edit</a></td>

                     </tr>
                  {% endfor %}




               </tbody>
```

**Please HELP me!!**

Comment: What are you getting? and what is the value in that variable??

Comment: I am getting blank.string.. it is the name of goal and meal type.

Comment: Paste `models.py` here.

Comment: check my answer below plz

Comment: g_name is giving blank string .

Comment: this same query giving perfect result on mysql command shell. but not on django

Comment: Edit the question and paste the models.py file in there.. 

The answer to your question would be `f.goal_id.g_name`

Comment: Thanks Man. really appreciated !